# Form for displaying and printing from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, forms

Is there a simple way to design a form for displaying (and printing on A4) data from an Excel sheet?

Lets say there are 200 rows in the Excel with 4 columns. I would like to make each row more readable by rearranging it like this on A4 paper (see attached diagram), instead of just printing in tabular form straight from Excel.

Can that be done without programming, but only field mapping from a form to Excel sheet?

Data entry not required. View and print only.
[A4 printed output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njGHm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are out of luck with Excel unless you can write a VBA macro to rearrange the table data.

One option is to use a Reporting tool e.g. you can link/import the Excel data into Access and build a Report, which will allow you freedom to show each record as you like.

Comment: Ok. Will give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a mail merge into Word, as if you're printing labels on a form. It's the same idea, just different data.

There are many examples online, no coding necessary.

Here's one from Microsoft, with plenty of links within in:

- [How to use the Mail Merge feature in Word to create and to print form letters that use the data from an Excel worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/318118/how-to-use-the-mail-merge-feature-in-word-to-create-and-to-print-form)

Comment: I guess mail merge will work only in a limited way for this purpose. I want more than one rowfrom the Excel sheet (say if 3 of them fit on a single A4 page) to be printed on a single sheet of A4.
As far as I understand, mail merge picks up values from a single row of Excel and fills them into a word template, prints that instance, and then moves to the next row in Excel to do the same on the next page (instance). So, I may not be able to get more than one row on a single sheet of paper.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Mail merge works too. There is an option to include more than one record/row from Excel in the same word page.